# Unable to process POST request for create action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip-5.0.0, and Rails 5.0.2.This is my code in controller

```
class PawsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_paw, only: [:show, :edit]
 def index
   @paws = Paw.all
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
  @paw = Paw.new
 end

def edit
end

def create
 @paw = Paw.new(paw_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @paw.save
    format.html { redirect_to @paw, notice: 'Paw was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @paw }

  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @paw.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end


private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_paw
  @paw = Paw.find(params[:id])
end


 def paw_params
   params.require(:paw).permit(:avatar,:name) if params[:avatar]
 end
end
```

Avatar here is the column for paw which stores images.In model I have added required validations for paperclip and validation for presence of name.

**Problem:** In *rails console* I am successfully able to open the image file from my computer and add it to the paw model i.e. **@paw.save** returns true in console, but in the browser it redirects me to the new_paw_url with two errors.
    *Name can't be blank.* and
    *Avatar can't be blank.*
There are no exceptions or errors thrown in between the process.I have no idea how should I fix this.

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PawsController#create as HTML
Parameters:  {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"zKpb2XFEG4FqX3aVQx9oyyGI9x2NpmF+lmt4eZy/3p3VZr2eWYvHLaEjS5AvisJ6iEbRm61SJkJSuTpMx4c0JA==", "paw"=>{"name"=>"Sheru", "gender"=>"Male", "breed"=>"", "dob"=>"", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x005608576e1f30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170323-14343-1o95nqx.jpg>, @original_filename="art.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"paw[avatar]\"; filename=\"art.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 Rendering paws/new.html.erb within layouts/application
 Rendered paws/_form.html.erb (15.8ms)
 Rendered paws/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.3ms)
 Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.6ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 326ms (Views: 287.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Feel free to ask for any other code snippets from me.

Comment: What do your parameters look like when you submit them?

Comment: I have added params.... params other than name and avatar have no validations

Comment: Nevermind, I just took a closer look at your params and see there's no belongs_to relationship. :/ Editing this comment since it had a useless idea.

Comment: I had thought of another model, to take care of name and other params. I created it with migrations and all....later I thought lets remove models and add simple columns.I think I failed in removing that model.Any ideas to fix......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paw_params method is breaking it.  Remove the if statement and it should work.  The problem you're having is that the params you're recieving through your controller are nested in the `params[paw]` hash and not the `params` hash.  Your paw_params if statement should be

```
params.require(:paw).permit(:avatar,:name) if params[:paw][:avatar]
```

Look at the console of your params hash and you'll see that Rails will nest all params submitted via a form helper within the class name of the object.  In this case it's paw.

```
"paw"=>{"name"=>"Sheru", "gender"=>"Male", "breed"=>"", "dob"=>"", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x005608576e1f30
```

More obviously:

`params[:name]`  `#nil`

`params[:paw][:name]` `#"Sheru"`

Also, it's not a good practice to add conditionals for strong_paramaters based on the presence of certain attributes.  If someone submits a name without an avatar, the name wont be permitted due to strong_parameters but would give the user poor feedback.  Instead you should use validations in your Paw model that requires the presence of both the name and avatar.

Comment: so the story was, there is some bug in validations for paperclip [look here](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/399) , which I tried to fix but it then threw another error  *ActionController::ParameterMissing paperclip* to resolove it I added if condition in the paw_params.But other attributes came and screwed up. I then tried to fix validations and remove if, ahhnd after some effort current layout of validation is working.....thanks a lot :)